# How to install golang compiler in solaris 11.3

Tags: installation, package, solaris

I am trying to install golang compiler in Solaris 11.3 but I am getting following error;

> pkg install: The requested change to the system attempts to install multiple actions
>   for link 'usr/perl5/pod' with conflicting attributes:

```
1 package delivers 'link mediator=perl mediator-priority=vendor mediator-version=5.22 path=usr/perl5/pod target=5.22/lib/pod':
    pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-522@5.22.1,5.12-5.12.0.0.0.122.0:20170510T193143Z
1 package delivers 'link path=usr/perl5/pod target=5.12/lib/pod':
    pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-512@5.12.5,5.11-0.175.3.0.0.30.0:20150821T171525Z
```

These packages may not be installed together.  Any non-conflicting set may
be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be installed.

The requested change to the system attempts to install multiple actions
for link 'usr/perl5/man' with conflicting attributes:

```
1 package delivers 'link mediator=perl mediator-priority=vendor mediator-version=5.22 path=usr/perl5/man target=5.22/man':
    pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-522@5.22.1,5.12-5.12.0.0.0.122.0:20170510T193143Z
1 package delivers 'link path=usr/perl5/man target=5.12/man':
    pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-512@5.12.5,5.11-0.175.3.0.0.30.0:20150821T171525Z
```

These packages may not be installed together.  Any non-conflicting set may
be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be installed.

The requested change to the system attempts to install multiple actions
for link 'usr/perl5/bin' with conflicting attributes:

```
1 package delivers 'link mediator=perl mediator-priority=vendor mediator-version=5.22 path=usr/perl5/bin target=5.22/bin':
    pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-522@5.22.1,5.12-5.12.0.0.0.122.0:20170510T193143Z
1 package delivers 'link path=usr/perl5/bin target=5.12/bin':
    pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-512@5.12.5,5.11-0.175.3.0.0.30.0:20150821T171525Z
```

These packages may not be installed together.  Any non-conflicting set may
be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be installed.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I installed Perl-5.22 then also it is giving the same error. After googling I found the following command to ignore runtime Perl-512.

> pkg change-facet facet.version-lock.runtime/perl-512=false

but I still getting this error which I mentioned above.
Please help me to sort out this error.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

if you are also getting the same error with installation of any package follow the given command:

```
pkg install --accept --licenses perl-512
pkg install --accept --licenses perl-522
pkg install golang-17
```

Comment: For me on Solaris 11.4 (which I realize isn't the version the OP is asking for), I had to use `pkg install pkg://solaris/developer/golang-17` for the last command, otherwise I would get the error "pkg install: 'golang-17' matches multiple packages".